# Lemon Seedling Trouble

Tags: trees, lemons

[image: lemon tree seedling]

Hi there,

I have 3 lemon tree seedlings that I’ve been growing since July 2017. Two of the seedlings are doing fine, but this one recently started to take a turn for the worse. The leaves have slowly been falling off and it hasn’t grown in at least 2 months. The stem is still green and I can see a tiny new green leaf growing at the very tip. I recently bought Jobe’s fertilizer to help give it a boost. Is there anything else I can do to help revive it?

Comment: How wet is that soil mixture? And what sort of lighting are you using?

Comment: Also the pot is too large for the plant.  Consider repotting in a smaller clay pot

Answer (score 3):

Lemon is a Mediterranean plant. She likes dry (and poor) soil.

I think you over-watered too much. Very very too much.  Especially in winter, keep the soil almost dry.